# How do I save the data I enter into a LabVIEW VI and restore it on when I reload?

Tags: configuration, save, load, settings, labview

In LabVIEW, I want to save data of controls on the front panel into a configuration file before I close VI file. When I load the VI later, I want to restore the values. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier and more elegant way is to use config files. 
You can save the configuration before closing your application and loading it at the initialization state.

Take a look at this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvQq27D88nQ

Comment: Yep, that's it - OpenG and MGI toolkit VIs save info to ini configuration files.

Comment: I tried this too, But the matter in this method is that I have to consider the all the controllers on by one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use out-of-the-box VIs from OpenG or MGI toolkits, to read/write all values from front panel controls from/to configuration ini file. Check this link - https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Program-Drafts/Save-Controls-to-Config-File-INI/tac-p/3497113/highlight/true#M11537.

You could install those toolkits using VI Package Manager (which is in most cases installed along with NI Software bundle, or could be downloaded and installed separately, https://vipm.jki.net/download).

Then, just when you close VI, use functions to write values to config file, and when VI is opened, just read those values from configuration file.

I was using OpenG functions, they could do exactly what you need.

Comment: Really helpful answer. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, @Malisha! If answer solves your question, you could also mark it as the answer - so it will be clearly visible, that the problem has solution.